# Gnupg - Decrypt file

Tags: gnupg

I'm trying to decrypt a file but I get the following:

```
gpg <file name>
gpg: encrypted with 2048-bit RSA key, ID 4A83B612, created 2018-02-19
      "user <email>"
gpg: decryption failed: secret key not available
```

When I list my keys using:

> gpg --list-keys

Here is the result:

```
    pub   2048R/0BBBBDB3 2018-02-19
    uid                  user <email>
    sub   2048R/4A83B612 2018-02-19
```

I understand that the sub key doesn't seem to be recognized.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the output of `gpg --list-secret-keys`.

Comment: I don't understand why but the output of gpg --list-secret-keys is empty...

Answer (score 1):

To decrypt you need the private key. Have a look at https://www.gnupg.org/gph/en/manual/x110.html:

> If you want to encrypt a message to Alice, you encrypt it using Alice's public key, and she decrypts it with her private key. If Alice wants to send you a message, she encrypts it using your public key, and you decrypt it with your key.

As the documentation states, only the recipient you specify by `--recipient` when encrypting can decrypt the message.

So in summary:

1. Encrypting uses the public key of the recicipient
2. Decrypting uses the private key of the recipient

Comment: Thank you for your reply. When I encrypted the file, I only used my public key since I was trying to encrypt a file for myself (no recipient).

Comment: Yourself is also a recipient. You need to have the private key for "user <email>" to decrypt. As stated in your comment above you don't seem to have the private key, which is why you can't decrypt.

Comment: I can see my private key in the GNU Privacy Assistant - Key Manager (a pair of yellow and blue keys) but the output of gpg --list-secret-keys is still blank.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to have an output of `gpg --list-secret-keys`

I still can't decrypt the file though. Here is the output of `gpg --output doc --decrypt doc.gpg`:

> gpg: encrypted with 2048-bit RSA key, ID 4A83B612, created 2018-02-19
>          "user "  gpg: decryption failed: secret key not available

Comment: I forgot to mention that I did import my secret key.